# What are some of the best practices for generating loving kindness?

Tags: reference-request, meditation-recommendation, loving-kindness, love

I came across many lectures from Ram Dass/Richard Alpert in the beginning of my meditation practice about a month ago, and I found the attitudes toward life and other people he espoused very liberating and were a good complement to the attention-focusing practice of samatha. I haven't found any good resources in the Buddhist school for something similar to Bhakti yoga a la Ram Dass. Moreover, even in Bhakti yoga, I haven't found and specific meditative practices to help bring about that very open, loving state of mind that listening to the lectures inspired.

Any recommendations for Buddhist resources similar to what Ram Dass put out? I just feel more comfortable in the Buddhist framework. Also, any specific meditations for generating that feeling?

Comment: Ven. Nanamoli's "Practice of Loving-Kindness" is strongly recommended: http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nanamoli/wheel007.html

Answer (score 1):

> Any recommendations for Buddhist resources similar to what Ram Dass put out?

I do not know about Ram Dass hence might not be similar but try:

- ["A Practical Bare-Bones guide to Metta Meditation"](http://www.dhammasukha.org/metta-barebones-booklet.html) by Bhante Vimalaramsi
- [Knowing and Seeing](http://www.dhammatalks.net/Books13/Pa-Auk-Sayadaw_Knowing-and-Seeing-4th-Ed-2010.pdf) by Ven Pa Auk Sayadaw
- [The Practice of Loving-Kindness](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nanamoli/wheel007.html)

Answer (score 1):

There's also a wonderful book by His Holiness' the Dalai Lama, How to Expand Love. Very clear step-by-step reflections.

[http://www.amazon.com/How-Expand-Love-Widening-Relationships/dp/0743269691](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0743269691)